# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n \frac {1}{2^r}\tan \left(\frac {1}{2^r}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n \frac {1}{2^r}\tan \left(\frac {1}{2^r}\right)$$

I tried to create a telescoping sum but I couldn't. The last step I could reach was turning the limit into $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n \left(\frac {1}{2^r(1-\tan (2^{-r+1})} -\frac {1}{2^r(1+\tan (2^{-r+1})}\right) $$

But couldn't proceed further. Also I thought about Riemann sums but it was a pure dead end.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Solution 1.** By the sine double-angle formula,

$$ \sin x = 2^n \sin(2^{-n}x) \prod_{k=1}^{n} \cos(2^{-k}x). $$

Now log-differentiating both sides gives

$$ \cot x = \frac{1}{2^n}\cot\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right) - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2^k}\tan\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right). $$

Taking $n\to\infty$ and simplifying gives

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}\tan\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right) = \frac{1}{x} - \cot x. $$

---

**Solution 2.** The above computation suggests the type of telescoping that we have to create. Indeed, by the tangent double-angle formula

$$ \frac{1}{2}\cot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = \frac{1-\tan^2(x/2)}{2\tan(x/2)} = \cot x $$

and hence

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2^k}\tan\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right)
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{1}{2^k}\cot\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right) - \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\cot\left(\frac{x}{2^{k-1}}\right) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2^n}\cot\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right) - \cot x.
\end{align*}

Taking $n\to\infty$ gives the same answer.